# Difference between laughing (gerund) and laughter(noun)

Tags: difference

May I know if the sentences below are correct. If not, why? Is there a difference between laughter and laughing? Thank you.

1. Make **laughing** a habit.
2. Make **laughter** a habit.
3. Make **exercise** a habit.
4. Make **exercising** a habit.

Comment: FYI, "May I know if the sentences below are correct?" is not commonly said in English.  `"May" is used to ask for permission` but what you are doing is simply asking a question.  It would be more appropriate to say, "Are the sentences below correct?" or (more polite and more unassuming) "Would you please let me know if the sentences below are correct?"

Answer (score 1):

**laughing** and **laughter** are both nouns. **laughing** is the activity: **laughter** is the product of that activity.

For the statement **Make X a habit**, X can either be an activity or a product:

> Make walking a habit *<- activity*
>   Make compassion a habit *<- product*

Some words can be used as both the product-noun, the activity-noun and the verb: examples are **exercise**, work, play, sleep. For these words, there is no need to use the gerund to refer to the activity: it is possible but not idiomatic.

Looking at your examples, all are grammatically correct. For sentences 1 and 2, there is no particular reason to prefer either, though I think the majority would prefer 2: this may be because of the proverb "Laughter is the best medicine". 3 is definitely preferable to 4, as we do not use the gerund where the verb-as-noun describes the activity.

> 1. Make laughing a habit. *<- refers to activity*
> 2. Make laughter a habit. *<- refers to product*
> 3. Make exercise a habit. *<- could refer to activity or product*
> 4. Make exercising a habit. *<- refers to activity*

Answer (score 0):

Since it comes from the verb, ***laughing*** describes the action. When one laughs, the outcome is ***laughter*** or a laugh.

Consider this: "I hear laughter" and "I hear laughing."

The first describes you hearing the sound, the second that your hear someone who laughs. Hence, the focus of the gerund is a little bit more on the action than the result.

Although I guess it's fuzzy with laugher, since the noun also entails the act of laughing.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/laughter

The same is with the excercise. Excercising focuses more on the actual doing than the inclusion of excercises in your habits.

Answer (score 0):

They are all correct.  2 and 3 are better.  I think it will be clearer to you with the following examples:

> *Laughter* is good for you.  *Laughter* is the best medicine.
>
> *Exercise* is good for you.  Regular *exercise* can help prevent fractures as you age.

Comment: I don't understand how the examples you provided help clarify the situation. What makes "Laughter is good for you." better than "Laughing is good for you"?

Comment: @ColleenV - I couldn't think of a reason, other than that these are set phrases which are very commonly used.  If you can think of a reason, I'm all ears.